Gaussian processes for Machine Learning, Rasmussen, Exercise 2.4
Problem
Let $var_n(f(x_*))$ be the predictive variance of a Gaussian process regression model at $x_*$ given a dataset of size $n$. The corresponding predictive variance using a dataset of only the first $n-1$ training points is denoted $var_{n−1}(f(x_*))$. Show that $var_n(f(x_*)) \leq var_{n−1}(f(x_*))$, i.e. that the predictive variance at $x_*$ cannot increase as more training data is obtained.
What I Tried
The hint refers to using a partitioned matrix to decompose $var_n(f(x_*)) = k(x_*, x_*) - k_*^\intercal (K + \sigma_n^2 I)^{-1} k_*$, where $k$ is the kernel function used in the Gaussian process regression, and $K$ is the $n \times n$ covariance matrix of kernel values for the training set. Then we can decompose $var_n(f(x_*))$ like so:
$$
K + \sigma_n^2 I =   \begin{bmatrix}
    K_{:n-1, :n-1} + \sigma_n^2 I &  K_{:n-1, n}\\
    K_{n, :n-1} & K_{n, n} + \sigma_n^2 & 
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Using the inversion of a block matrix formula that the hint refers to (see here), we can get
$$
(K+\sigma_n^2I)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
   \widetilde{P} & \widetilde{Q}\\
    \widetilde{R} & \widetilde{S}
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$
where in particular $\widetilde{P} = (K_{:n-1, :n-1} + \sigma_n^2I)^{-1} + (K_{:n-1, :n-1} + \sigma_n^2I )^{-1} K_{:n-1, n} M K_{n, :n-1} (K_{:n-1, :n-1} + \sigma_n^2 I)^{-1}$  where $M = ( K_{n, n} + \sigma_n^2 -  K_{n, :n-1} ( K_{:n-1, :n-1} + \sigma_n^2 I)  K_{:n-1, n})^{-1}$.
Furthermore, expanding $var_n(f(x_*))$, we can get
$$
\begin{align*}
var_n(f(x_*)) &= k(x_*, x_*) - 
\begin{bmatrix}
   k_{*, :n-1}^\intercal & k_{*, n}^\intercal
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   \widetilde{P} & \widetilde{Q}\\
   \widetilde{R} & \widetilde{S}
  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   k_{*, :n-1} \\
 k_{*, n}
  \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \underbrace{k(x_*, x_*) - k^{\intercal}_{*, :n-1} (K_{:n-1, :n-1} + \sigma_n^2I)^{-1} k_{*, :n-1}}_{var_{n-1}(f(x_*))} - \text{[some unwieldy terms]}.
\end{align*}
$$
This seems to be what the hint is getting at but I'm having no luck proving that $\text{[some unwieldy terms]}$ must be positive.

You could be interested in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180248/predictive-variance-of-a-gaussian-process

Thank you for the link - it is helpful, though it is discussing a slightly stronger claim which is when the variance should go to 0, and is only sometimes true. The claim in Rasmussen's exercise is weaker - that the variance is non-increasing, but is true all the time.
